# How do I set the Microsoft Teams background for all meetings?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I can set the background (e.g. "blurred") right before answering the call and also during the call. But how can I set it in general so that I always have the same background for every call?

Answer (score 0):

Once background is set it will persist in all your meetings and calls until you change it again. Please have a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-background-for-a-teams-meeting-f77a2381-443a-499d-825e-509a140f4780) document.